# Special Case of A.M-G.M Inequality.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How can we prove this special case of $\text{A.M.-G.M.}$ Inequality,  that is:

If The Geometric Mean of $n$ positive  real numbers is equal to $1.$ Prove that their Arithmetic Mean is greater than or equal to $1.$

I know the proof by induction but I want to know if there is a proof without using induction or calculus.
 Note:I don't want a proof for general $\text{A.M.-G.M.}$ Inequality, I just want a proof for this special case.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mu=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}$$
$$l=\sqrt[n]{x_1\,x_2\,\cdots\,x_n}$$
we know $e^x>1+x$. For $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ set
$$x=\frac{x_i}{\mu}-1$$
we have
$$\large e^{\frac{x_i}{\mu}-1}\ge \frac{x_i}{\mu} $$
therefore
\begin{align}
  & \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{e}^{\frac{{{x}_{i}}}{\mu }-1}}}\ge \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{{{x}_{i}}}{\mu }}\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,{{e}^{-n+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{{{x}_{i}}}{\mu }}}}\ge \frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{x}_{i}}}}{{{\mu }^{n}}} \\ 
\end{align}
and
$$1\ge \frac{{{l}^{n}}}{{{\mu }^{n}}}\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,{{\mu }^{n}}\ge {{l}^{n}}\Rightarrow \mu \ge l$$

Comment: Then how to prove that $e^x>1+x$ if $x>0$.

Comment: $$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+...$$

Comment: Small nit, your usage of $e^x$ is actually over all reals not just non-negative, so while $e^x\ge x+1$ for all reals, that proof isn't quite so obvious.

Comment: Why does my solution isn't quite so obvious?

Comment: For $x =-0.9$, how does your one liner show $e^x\ge x+1$ ? And you have not even included negative numbers in your statement to start with.

Comment: I just prove this inequality for positive real numbers

Comment: You have $x =\frac{x_i}{\mu}-1$, why can't some of the positive $x_i$ be lesser than their mean?

Comment: yeah, you are right

Comment: @ Macavity so Thanks